# Writing several unit definitions?

Tags: io, ocaml, program-entry-point

I've seen many OCaml programs that have all their functions at the top and then a unit definition at the end, like:

```
let rec factorial num =
  if num = 0 then 1
  else num * factorial (num-1)

let () =
  let num2 = read_int () in
    print_int (factorial num2)
```

Why is this? Does it act like a main function? If so, you shouldn't be able to use several of them right?
What is the best way to handle several input for example? Writing several unit definitions?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a unit expression at the top level of a module acts like the main function of the module. I.e., it gets executed at the time the program is started.

You can have many unit expressions anywhere you can have one unit expression. The `;` operator is specifically intended for such cases:

```
let () =
    Printf.printf "hello\n";
    Printf.printf "world\n"
```

As a side comment, I often write a main function in my main module:

```
let main () =
    (* main calculation of program *)

let () = main ()
```

This is possibly a holdover from all the years I wrote C code.

I have also seen this in other people's code (possibly there are a lot of us who used to write C code).

Comment: It makes the entry point of the program more clear to a reader, and enforces `main` to be `unit -> unit`.

Answer (score 2):

I really like Jeffrey's answer, but in case if you want extra details and what to know what `let () = foo` means here is some extracurricular reading.

Abstractly speaking the operation of OCaml programs could be defined as a machine that reduces expressions until they become irreducible. And an irreducible expression is called a *value*. For example, `5 + 3` is reduced to `8` and there is no other way to reduce `8` so `8` is a value. A more complex example of a value is `(fun x -> x + 1)`. And a more complex example of expression would be

```
(fun x -> x + 1) 5
```

Which is reduced to `6`.

The whole semantics of the language is defined as a set of such reduction rules. And a program in OCaml is an ordered list of definitions of the form,

```
let <pattern> = <expression>
```

So that when an OCaml program is evaluated (executed) it reduces the  part of each definition and assigns it to the pattern on the left-hand side, e.g.,

```
let 5 = 2 + 3
```

is a valid definition in OCaml. It will reduce the `2 + 3` expression to `5` and then try to match the resulting value with the left-hand side. If it matches, then the next definition is evaluated, and so on. If it doesn't the program is terminated.

Here `5` is a very simple value that matches only with `5` and, in general, your values will be more complex. However, there is a value that is even more primitive than `5`. It is a value of type `unit` that has only one inhabitant, denoted as `()`. And this is also the value, to which colloquially expressions with side effects are reduced. Since in OCaml every expression must reduce to a value, we need a value that represents no value, and that is unit. For example `print_endline "foo"` reduces to `()` with a side effect of emitting string `foo` to the standard output.

Therefore, when we write

```
let foo () = print_endline "foo"
let () = foo ()
```

We evaluate (reduce) the function `foo` until it reaches the `()` value that indicates that we fully reduced `foo ()`.

We could also use a wildcard matcher and write

```
let _ = foo ()
```

or bind the result to a variable, e.g.,

```
let bar = foo ()
```

But it is considered a good style to use `()` on the left-hand side of an expression that evaluates to `()` to indicate that the right-hand side doesn't produce any interesting value. It also prevents common errors, e.g.,

```
let () = foo
```

will yield an error saying that `unit -> unit` and can't be matched with `unit` and even provide a hint: `Did you forget to provide` ()' as argument?`